# Link Microsoft Authentication to AngularJS SPA frontend

Tags: angularjs, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a ASP.NET Core Web API that I am trying to set up office365 authentication on. The frontend when you load it should be redirected to the azure sign in page and if the account details are correct they should be returned to the SPA application.

The SPA and API are in different applications. I understand how to do in an MVC context using asp.net.core MVC it's the separating the 2 API and SPA.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Can you share some code, such as `startup`?

Comment: I have an idea that you can use msal in Spa and add filter in the api app, so that when you visit the api directly it returns 'forbidden' because of no access token in request head and when you visit page view it redirect to login page to make you sign in. Take it into consideration?

Comment: I’m thinking that’s going to have to be the way @tiny-wa thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks @Tiny's comment is correct, move it to answer to help others:

> you can use msal in Spa and add filter in the api app, so that when you visit the api directly it returns 'forbidden' because of no access token in request head and when you visit page view it redirect to login page to make you sign in.